# How can i do this simple thing in Python from Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

Simple Matlab code: e.g `A(5+(1:3))`   -> gives `[A(6), A(7), A(8)]`

In the above, `A` is a vector or a matrix. For instance:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
A(5+(1:3)) 
ans =
     6    7    8
```

Note that MATLAB indexing starts at 1, not 0.

How can i do the same in Python?

Comment: Can you maybe explain what the matlab code does in words?

Comment: I edited your question with an example and some text to make it more clear. I'm quite sure it's correct, but please do a rollback or edit if it's not. I'm assuming you don't want to use linear indexes for a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for slicing behavior

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

>>> A[5:8]
[6, 7, 8]
```

If `A` is some function that you want to call with parameters `6`, `7`, and `8`, you could use a list comprehension.

```
answers = [A(6+i) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: A is an array and not a function

Comment: @GeorgeLaza I notice that now, OP edited his post after I posted this answer.

Comment: actually it is not a simple slicing because the indexed will be different. The code is this in Matlab and i want to transfer it in Python: e.g my_array(num_samples+(1:m))

Answer (score 1):

You want to do two things.

First, create a range `(5 + (1:3))` which could be done in Python like `range(number)`.

Second, apply a function to each range index. This could be done with `map` or a `for` loop.

The `for` loop solutions have been addressed, so here's a `map` based one:

```
result = map(A,your_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
x = 5 
f = 1 # from
t = 3 # till
print [x+i for i in range(f,t+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use subscripts to create an array which is a subset of the whole array:
   subset_list = A[6:8]

Answer (score 0):

in python u can do it easily by A[5:5+3] . u can reference the values 5 and 3 by variables also like
    b=5
    c=3
    a[b:b+c]